# How to delete reminder in android on click of button

Tags: android, calendar, reminders

I am unable to delete single events in calender android. So far I am set reminder and display all set reminder in list, now I want to delete reminder on button click. If any idea then please 
let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1.Read calender uri first
2.get event id and pass to cursor

> ```
>             Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
>             int eventId =EventNameText.getId();
>             Log.d("OnClickID",""+eventId);
>             Uri newuri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, eventId);
>             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,newuri);
>             int cs=context.getContentResolver().delete(newuri,null, null);
> ```